# Error al consumir WCF con soapui

Tags: wcf, soapui

Al intentar consumir el servicio web de la DIAN de facturación electrónica V2 que realiza autenticación con un certificado digital me arroja el siguiente error en el xml respuesta:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Alguien sabe que más se debe configurar para que la prueba sea exitosa en SoapUi

Comment: ¿Puede ser que tengas que incluir una cabecera de seguridad oasis en el soap?

Answer (score 0):

Para poderte ayudar mejor, deberías compartir el soap del request también.
Cuando yo configuré mi SoapUI recuerdo que seguí los pasos del anexo técnico y adicionalmente ajusté algo más que no estaba en ese paso a paso. Creo que fue con relación a la URL del wsdl. Revisa bien que si estés apuntando al ambiente correcto.

Te comparto el soap que genera mi SoapUI al consumir el método SendBillSync por si la referencia te ayuda a configurar mejor el tuyo:

```
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia"><soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516322120"><wsu:Created>2019-12-04T20:31:56.322Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2019-12-05T13:11:56.322Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516231115">MIIGwDC aquí van más caracteres del token... jOBoPhWczFwppM7UpTrQWEUPwi1dRSPBHwYQkrso6vA==</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516296119" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa soap wcf" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516231118"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap wcf" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>dOUMF7Nhw0PJcUcbkipBq5lGp9ztkLgXobo1izBhlVI=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>OPEtl/dIgwsuCKFsw073uhpAC5XaDiqkmIbQ5F5ELswD2ZXB5aJzljSpLMP3RRF3J4kSeaFtXxBFMrL+OQXk/2UsMCc6CUYnoJ7hpCeYS1RcAs9Y3Vc/gaPZR+b0ijQXZ9J7ZMOxmnrM2jeykSWa5qJYbwWXPO43BlYh49x2GjW0yYXcO6bxrLbrFKa9YSgsG6l9hzaLqFRf8HWwozL9C2GKvcSmq/2oGt+MpClX8SzNX+xuuQZmQbkXcr+cMTXv69rp4IIZshwL/TLbvnzf//mZotxBE8lTLouSUcCSwGMNThbjOnIwqCBnmLn38NWG5ISA12WHsWiSXsUgK2QzCw==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516231116"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516231117"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516231115" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security><wsa:Action>http://wcf.dian.colombia/IWcfDianCustomerServices/SendBillSync</wsa:Action><wsa:To wsu:Id="id-8AE11F34CFBA53E9291575491516231118" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">https://vpfe-hab.dian.gov.co/WcfDianCustomerServices.svc</wsa:To></soap:Header>  <soap:Body>
  <wcf:SendBillSync>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <wcf:fileName>?</wcf:fileName>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <wcf:contentFile>UEsDBBQAAAAIAMJOUk/D/uSbhRcAADRfAAA+ABwAaG9tZS9vcmFjbGUvcGFjb19odG1sL2xvZ3NfcGFjby9mYWNlX2Y4MDAwNTg4MDkwMDAzYjAyMzY3My54bWxVVAkAAwzSqV0M0qlddXgLAAEE9Q...
     hvbWUvb3JhY2xlL3BhY29faHRtbC9sb2dzX3BhY28vZmFjZV9mODAwMDU4ODA5MDAwM2IwMjM2NzMueG1sVVQFAAMM0qlddXgLAAEE9QEAAAT1AQAAUEsFBgAAAAABAAEAhAAAAP0XAAAAAA==</wcf:contentFile>
  </wcf:SendBillSync>
```